# Access state in error controller of .NET Core 5 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two controllers, `MyController` and `ErrorController`.

I set up exception handing using

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/detail");
```

In `MyController`, my action instantiates an object with some state information.

If an exception is thrown, I am looking to return a response that contains that state information, assuming the information has been populated by the time the exception is thrown.

Is it possible to somehow access state instantiated in `MyController`, from `MyErrorController`? I was originally thinking of some how using dependency injection, but can't access `IServiceCollection` from the controller. Seemed a bit dirty to me as well.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't get the question but if you just want to just pass data between two controllers, you can use TempData.

Comment: You use the app.UseExceptionHandler middleware, and then you want to customize some exception information and trigger the exception in the MyController method?